# Getting "ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token" when splitting routes into different files/modules

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I'm using [csurf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf) in my [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) project. I have 3 files:

- **app.js** - Main entry point
- **routes/index.js** - Index routes
- **routes/users.js** - User routes

It's standard boilerplate when using [express application generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

I have a route in **index.js**:

```
router.get('/', csrfProtection, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
      csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
  });
});
```

The page for this route contains a form that has a hidden field with csrf token:

```
input(name='_csrf', type='hidden', value='#{csrfToken}')
```

All works fine and I can see the csrf token in the source.

When the form is submitted it's handled buy the route in **routes/users.js**:

```
router.post('/login', csrfProtection, function(req, resp) {
    if(!validator.isAlphanumeric(req.username))
        console.log('Not alphanumeric');

    ...
});
```

It appears the problem is something to do with both files having to create new instances of `csrf`, and `csrfToken`. At the head of both route files I require them like so:

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });
```

If I put the login route into **routes/index.js** it works fine, which has made me think maybe both instances are using different csrf tokens.

Any ideas?

Comment: One common mistake is adding csurf middle-ware before body-parser middle-ware.

Also  either a session middleware or cookie-parser must be to be initialized first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe it is using different CSRF tokens. I got around the issue by defining an init function in my sub-modules, and then passing the CSRF token into that. That way the CSRF token is only created once. I think creating the CSRF token in app.js is probably best, and then you can pass it into your various sub-modules.

Ex:

in users.js:

```
function init(router, csrfProtection) {
    router.post('/login', csrfProtection, function(req, resp) {
        if(!validator.isAlphanumeric(req.username))
            console.log('Not alphanumeric');
        ...
    });
}

module.exports.init = init;
```

in app.js:

```
...initialize router and CSRF protection...

var users = require('./users.js');
users.init(router, csrfProtection);
```